# Casting a Spring's Proxy object to the actual runtime class

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Spring, at one point I would like to cast the object to its actual runtime implementation.

Example:

```
Class MyClass extends NotMyClass {
    InterfaceA a;
    InterfaceA getA() { return a; }

    myMethod(SomeObject o) { ((ImplementationOfA) getA()).methodA(o.getProperty()); }
}
```

That yells a `ClassCastException` since `a` is a `$ProxyN` object. Although in the beans.xml I injected a bean which is of the class `ImplementationOfA` .

**EDIT 1**
I extended a class and I need to call for a method in `ImplementationOfA`. So I think I need to cast. The method receives a parameter.

**EDIT 2**

I better rip off the target class:

```
private T getTargetObject(Object proxy, Class targetClass) throws Exception {
    while( (AopUtils.isJdkDynamicProxy(proxy))) {
        return (T) getTargetObject(((Advised)proxy).getTargetSource().getTarget(), targetClass);
    }
    return (T) proxy; // expected to be cglib proxy then, which is simply a specialized class
}
```

I know it is not very elegant but works.

All credits to http://www.techper.net/2009/06/05/how-to-acess-target-object-behind-a-spring-proxy/
Thank you!

Comment: This is bad practice, the actual implementation class shouldn't be relevant.  However, it is possible, depending on how is your proxy being created.

Comment: If you need to call a method on `ImplementationOfA`, then add that method to the `InterfaceA` interface, or define a second interface and add the method to that.

Comment: Well, I know it is not ideal, but the class I'm extending implements an Interface, and due to application requirements I cannot modify neither InterfaceA nor NotMyClass.

Comment: @Udo get rid of these requirements, then.

Comment: Can you introduce a new interface then?

Comment: I solved it by accessing the target class.

Comment: just a note: `while` does not loop in above code, `if` is enough.

Answer (score 14):

Now you can use

```
AopTestUtils.getTargetObject(proxy)
```

.

The implementation is the same of @siulkilulki sugestion, but it's on Spring helper

Answer (score 13):

For me version from **EDIT 2** didn't worked. Below one worked:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
protected <T> T getTargetObject(Object proxy) throws Exception {
    while( (AopUtils.isJdkDynamicProxy(proxy))) {
        return (T) getTargetObject(((Advised)proxy).getTargetSource().getTarget());
    }
    return (T) proxy; // expected to be cglib proxy then, which is simply a specialized class
}
```

Usage:

```
    UserServicesImpl serviceImpl = getTargetObject(serviceProxy);
    serviceImpl.setUserDao(userDAO);
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically when you use AOP in Spring, Spring build a Proxy for you. You have two option:

1. when you apply an aspect on a bean that implements an interface, in
   this case Spring use JdkDynamicProxy
2. when your spring bean don't implements any interface and if you have
   cglib 2.2 in you classpath, consider that from spring 3.2.x you have
   cglib in the spring container by default, spring use a special
   proxy called CGLibProxy.

The key point here is that when an aspect is applied on your bean Spring will instance a proxy and if you try to perform a cast you will get an exception.

I hope tha this can help you