# Is it possible to unproxy a Spring bean?

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring bean, let's say:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) 
public class AImpl implements A {

     public void setSomeDependency(D dependency) {
         // This setter DOES NOT BELONG to interface A
     }
}

<bean id="aImpl" class="AImpl"/>
```

Now I want to integration test it, but first I need to mock the dependency `D`, because it does too much stuff. Since the `AImpl` implements an interface and contains a transactional annotation, the generated proxy is only compatible with the interface `A`, so I can do this:

```
@Inject @Named("aImpl")
private A a;
```

but cannot:

```
@Inject @Named("aImpl")
private AImpl a;
```

As a result, I can't mock my dependency.

Please note that adding `void setSomeDependency(D dependency)` to interface `A` is not an option, as it has no business meaning. Neither it is using the `proxy-target-class="true"`, as it breaks a whole lot of other beans (this attribute affects all beans in the context).

Is there a way to unproxy the injected bean `A`, so I could cast it to `AImpl`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting a Spring's Proxy object to the actual runtime class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976247/casting-a-springs-proxy-object-to-the-actual-runtime-class)

Comment: @skaffman: thanks for pointing it out, I added that question to spring tag FAQ

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(AopUtils.isAopProxy(a) && a instanceof Advised) {
    Object target = ((Advised)a).getTargetSource().getTarget();
    AImpl ai = (AImpl)target;
}
```

Bonus: in Scala I am using the following equivalent function for the very same purpose:

```
def unwrapProxy(a: AnyRef) = a match {
    case advised: Advised if(AopUtils.isAopProxy(advised)) => 
                            advised.getTargetSource.getTarget
    case notProxy => notProxy
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you really saved me. BTW, I just visited Oslo for the first time, now I don't wonder why you spend so much time on SO (no offence meant, but the weather is not encouraging) :)

Comment: Glad I could help. I liked your comment so much that I even quoted it on my profile page ;-).

Answer (score 27):

With the introduction of Spring 4.2.RC1, there is now a dedicated utility class in the `spring-test` module that handles this case for you.

The class is called `AopTestUtils` and provides the methods:

- `getTargetObject` (unwraps only the top-level proxy)
- `getUltimateTargetObject` (unwraps multiple levels of proxies if they exist).

Check out the relevant [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/efe3a35da871a7ef34148dfb65d6a96cac1fccb9) as well as the respective [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13005).

Comment: Thanks for providing an updated answer, this is a better solution for most people as it requires much less logic.