# Should Mockito be used with MockMvc's webAppContextSetup in Spring 4?

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I'm having difficulties getting Mockito and MockMvc working together when I use the webAppContextSetup together. I'm curious if it's because I'm mixing the two in a way they were never intended.

Source: https://github.com/zgardner/spring-boot-intro/blob/master/src/test/java/com/zgardner/springBootIntro/controller/PersonControllerTest.java

Here is the test I'm running:

```
package com.zgardner.springBootIntro.controller;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import static java.lang.Math.toIntExact;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup;

import com.zgardner.springBootIntro.Application;
import com.zgardner.springBootIntro.service.PersonService;
import com.zgardner.springBootIntro.model.PersonModel;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class PersonControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Mock
    private PersonService personService;

    @InjectMocks
    private PersonController personController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        initMocks(this);

        // beanFactory.destroySingleton("personController");
        // beanFactory.registerSingleton("personController", personController);

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getPersonById() throws Exception {
        Long id = 999L;
        String name = "Person name";

        when(personService.findById(id)).thenReturn(new PersonModel(id, name));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/person/getPersonById/" + id))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(toIntExact(id))))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is(name)));
    }
}
```

I was expecting that when mockMvc performed the mock of that HTTP call, it would use the PersonController I defined in my test. But when I debug through, it's using the PersonController which was created by the SpringJunit4ClassRunner on the test boot up.

I found two ways to get this to work:

1. Inject the bean factory, remove the old personController singleton, and add my own. This is ugly, and I am not a fan.
2. Wire everything up using the standaloneSetup instead of webAppContextSetup. I may do this instead as I don't have to touch the bean factory.

Here are some different articles I've found that somewhat touch on the topic:

- [Spring Tutorial - Building REST Services](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/) This just autowires in the repos to clear out the data before the integration test takes place.
- [Use Spring MVC Test framework and Mockito to test controllers](http://markchensblog.blogspot.com/2013/02/use-spring-mvc-test-framework-and.html) This uses Mockito along with webAppContextSetup, but this is in Spring 3. (I'm using Spring Boot)
- [Unable to mock Service class in Spring MVC Controller tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207069/421923) This uses the standaloneSetup, which does work in my case too.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

You might be interested in the [new testing features](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4) coming in Spring Boot 1.4  (specifically the new `@MockBean` annotation). This [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-test/src/test/java/sample/test/web/UserVehicleControllerTests.java) shows how a service can be mocked and used with a controller test.

Comment: Mock beans are the way to go!

Answer (score 3):

For some reason the Mockito annotations `@Mock` et `@InjectMocks` won't work in this case.

Here's how I managed to make it work :

- Instantiate the `personService` bean manually using your own Test context
- make Mockito create a mock for this `personService`.
- let Spring inject these mocks in the controller `PersonController`.

You should have your TestConfig :

```
@Configuration
public class ControllerTestConfig {

  @Bean
  PersonService personService() {
    return mock(PersonService.class);
  }

}
```

In your `PersonControllerTest`, you won't need the `personController` anymore, since it's managed by the `mockMvc` through the `perform` method. You also don't need to execute `initMocks()` because you initialize your mocks manually inside the Spring config. You should have something like :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Application.class, ControllerTestConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class PersonControllerTest {

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

  @Autowired
  PersonService personService;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void getPersonById() throws Exception {
    Long id = 999L;
    String name = "Person name";

    when(personService.findById(id)).thenReturn(new PersonModel(id, name));

    mockMvc.perform(get("/person/getPersonById/" + id))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(toIntExact(id))))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is(name)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use Mockito to fake Spring beans with usage of `@Primary` and `@Profile` annotations. [I wrote a blog post about this technique.](https://lkrnac.net/blog/2015/12/mock-spring-bean-v2/) It also contains link to fully working example hosted on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

To extend florent's solution, I encountered performance issues and extensibility issues creating separate configurations for every controller test which needed a different set of service mocks. So instead, I was able to mock out my application's service layer by implementing a BeanPostProcessor alongside my tests which replaces all `@Service` classes with mocks:

```java
@Component
@Profile("mockService")
public class AbcServiceMocker implements BeanPostProcessor {

  private static final String ABC_PACKAGE = "com.mycompany.abc";

  @Override
  public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
    if (StringUtils.startsWith(bean.getClass().getPackage().getName(), ABC_PACKAGE)) {
      if (AnnotationUtils.isAnnotationDeclaredLocally(Service.class, bean.getClass())
          || AnnotationUtils.isAnnotationInherited(Service.class, bean.getClass())) {
        return mock(bean.getClass());
      }
    }
    return bean;
  }

  @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
    return bean;
  }
}
```

I enabled these mocks in specific tests with an `@ActiveProfiles` annotation:

```java
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:/WEB-INF/application-context.xml"})
@ActiveProfiles("mockService")
public class AbcControllerTest {

  private MockMvc mvc;

  @Before
  public final void testBaseSetup() {
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
  }
```

Lastly, the injected Mockito mocks were wrapped in an AopProxy causing Mockito's `expect` and `verify` calls to fail. So I wrote a utility method to [unwrap them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033874/mocking-a-property-of-a-cglib-proxied-service-not-working):

```java
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  protected <T> T mockBean(Class<T> requiredType) {
    T s = context.getBean(requiredType);
    if (AopUtils.isAopProxy(s) && s instanceof Advised) {
      TargetSource targetSource = ((Advised) s).getTargetSource();
      try {
        return (T) targetSource.getTarget();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error resolving target", e);
      }
    }
    Mockito.reset(s);
    return s;
  }
```