# @SpyBean not working with Pact and JUnit 5

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, pact, pact-jvm

I'm trying to use the `@SpyBean` to mock a method of a `@Component` and doesn't work. `@MockBean` works (followed the [example](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/pact-jvm-provider-spring)). I've tried, read and researched many ways but couldn't make it work.

Here's the example:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment. DEFINED_PORT)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@Provider("MyMicroService")
@PactFolder("../../../pacts")
internal class ClientContracts {

    @SpyBean
    private lateinit var myService: MyService

    @TestTemplate
    @ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider::class)
    fun pactVerificationTestTemplate(context: PactVerificationContext) {
        context.verifyInteraction()
    }

    @State("default", "NO_DATA")
    fun toDefaultState() {
        reset(processService)
    }
}
```

(I super simplified the test function so it's easier to read, I'd be actually doing `doReturn(...).when(...).blah()`)

I'm always getting the "not a mock" error, because the object is always the bean wrapped by Spring CGLIB:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: Argument should be a mock, but is: class com.blah.MyServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9712a2a5
    at com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.MockitoKt.reset(Mockito.kt:36)
...
```

I've tried:

- with `@SpringJUnitConfig`
- with a separate `@TestConfiguration`, but got resolved to same above bean
- Using `Mockito.initAnnotations(this)` in a `@BeforeEach`
- and more, I've tried with so many combinations that I can't remember...

Is there something that I'm missing? Or an option that I don't know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Above issue is not related to the pact or pact JVM library
2. The issue is not about spring

   - Spring - I use spring with mockito and it works, the simple example is:

```
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.doReturn
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.SpyBean
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension

@ExtendWith(value = [SpringExtension::class])
@SpringBootTest(
 webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
 classes = [Application::class]
)
internal class processorIntegrationTest : IntegrationTest() {

 @SpyBean
//    @MockBean
 private lateinit var processor: Processor;

 @Test
 internal fun abcd() {
     doReturn("something").`when`(processor).get()

     val get = processor.get()
     assertThat(get).isEqualTo("something")
 }
}
```

3. Mockito - `mockito_kotlin` or `mockito` extension works with `SpyBean`
4. Issue is about `mockito + CGLIB`

   - CGLIB - from your logs feels like `class com.blah.MyServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9712a2a5` there is a wrapper on top of your service implementation which is `SpyBean`. 
     Which means CGLIB wrapper is not and the error is for that. 
     Try removing CGLIB wrapper and it will work

Comment: Thanks for taking your time for this Gopinath. The CGLIB wrapper is not something I control (and only appears with the SpyBean). How would you unwrap the service or avoid the cglib wrapper altogether?

Comment: Offcourse you can unwarp CGLIB wrapper & test
Check this one for how to unwrap CGLIB  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033874/mocking-a-property-of-a-cglib-proxied-service-not-working

Comment: It worked. Thank you! Didn't know that there was a test utility for that. I'd still like to know the MockBean doesn't need it though. Maybe a story for another day :)

Comment: Good to hear that.