# doNothing() not working with @Autowired fields mocked in Spring

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking, mockito

I have Autowired a field in Test class

```
@Autowired
private AbcDAO abcDAO;
```

and used it like this

```
doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(abcDAO).methodName(xyz);
```

or

```
doNothing().when(abcDAO).methodName(xyz);
```

I have mocked this DAO class in spring files like this

```
<bean id="abcDAO" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock"  >
        <constructor-arg value="a.b.c.abcDAO" />
    </bean>
```

I get `NotAMockException Argument passed to when() is not a mock.`

When I use `@Mock annotation like this

```
@Mock
    private AbcDAO abcDAO;
```

in the test class directly (instead of @Autowiring it and mocking in spring), it works fine.

Why does it happen?

Edit:

Ok, so let me tell you the reason of doing so.

We have a service X and I want to write junits for the APIs of 'X'. Junits are written in such a way that I create a client and call these APIs. I am not calling the methods directly where @Mock and @Inject mocks can be used.

I am not sure if it is clear but this is the use case when mocking in spring file is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer: [why-does-mockito-think-this-autowired-bean-is-null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847545/why-does-mockito-think-this-autowired-bean-is-null)

`Mockito.mock` does not take a `String` but `Class<?>`. As it stated in the other question. Is there REALLY a good reason to attempt to create the mock in a Spring context?

Comment: And if you do have a REALLY good reason, why not using [springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home)?

Comment: I tried the approach suggested there as well.

<bean id="classInstance" class="java.lang.Class" factory-method="forName">
  <constructor-arg value="a.b.abcDAO" />
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="abcDAO" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock"  >
  <constructor-arg ref="classInstance" />
 </bean>

But again I am getting the same error.

Comment: Again, it is not suggested to attempt to do so. I would consider it an anti-pattern. Otherwise, try Alban's suggestion of spingockito.

Comment: added the reason behind doing it. will look into springockito. Thanks!