# How to get real className from a Lazy bean in Java

Tags: java, reflection, lazy-evaluation

I'm working a lot with java reflection, and i'm using a map to store metadata from each bean in the application. I use the className as a key, so, the problem is that when a ask for the className of a bean).

```
bean.getClass().getName()
```

I can get two different results, depending if the bean is lazy loaded or not (some relations are lazy, some aren't, but i want to work with both of them.

For example, the Class:

```
package com.factorit.beans;<br>
public class Task  implements java.io.Serializable {
```

If called in a normal loaded object, it returns:

```
com.factorit.beans.Task
```

but if called in a lazy initialized object, it returns

```
com.factorit.beans.Task$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f9d61939
```

I was wondering if there is a way to get this, or if I have to parse the String.

Thank you so much for any help or advice.

**EDIT:** 
Just to add some info:
My Lazy annotattions look like this:

```
@javax.persistence.ManyToOne(fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY)
```

and I'm using Struts 2.1.8.1, Hibernate 3 and Spring 2.5.6.

Comment: Will unwrapping CGLIB proxy [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8121671/605744) work for you?

Comment: Hi @TomaszNurkiewicz. I tried what is on the post you pointed, but all the options give me false as result. 
 * AopUtils.isAopProxy(item)
 * AopUtils.isCglibProxy(item)
 * AopUtils.isJdkDynamicProxy(item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If was debuging struts2-json-plugin 2.1.8.1, and in the method `JSONWritter.bean(Object object)`
I found that they are using this line

```
if (clazz.getName().indexOf("$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$") > -1) {
```

so, if even them have to parse the string, I suppouse there is no better way.
Thank you @TomaszNurkiewicz for your help.