# Is there a newer approach to Spring AOP and mockito?

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, aop

I have managed to solve a problem with Spring-boot aop and mocking test services using an approach detailed in [Spring AOP Aspect not working using Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902389/spring-aop-aspect-not-working-using-mockito). This thread is over 6 years old.

Are there any newer approaches out there?

**EDIT** adding more detail from my specific implementation.

Controller:

```java
@RestController
public class EndpointController {
    
    private EndpointService endpointService;
    
    @Autowired    
    public EndpointController(EndpointService endpointService) {
        this.endpointService = endpointService;
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/endpoint", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private @ResponseBody EndpointResponse doSomething(/* ... */, @RequestBody SomeObject someObject) throws Exception {
        return endpointService.doSomething(someObject);
    }
}
```

In my test class, I have:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class EndpointControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldBeSuccessfulAccessingTheEndpoint() throws Exception {
        SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject(/* values */);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String payload = mapper.writeValueAsString(someObject);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/endpoint").contentType(MediaType.APPLICTION_JSON).content(payload)).andExpect(status().isOK));
    }
}
```

It fails and throws a NullPointerException. When debugging, the `endpointService` is always null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the annotation @MockBean now. It's some sort of wrapped mockito in spring testing.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ExampleTests {

     @MockBean
     private ExampleService service;

     @Autowired
     private UserOfService userOfService;

     @Test
     public void testUserOfService() {
         given(this.service.greet()).willReturn("Hello");
         String actual = this.userOfService.makeUse();
         assertEquals("Was: Hello", actual);
     }

     @Configuration
     @Import(UserOfService.class) // A @Component injected with ExampleService
     static class Config {
     }
 }
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html

Comment: it did not work for me. I'm just going to edit the question to provide more details.