# Constraint Annotation Types

Tags: java

I have created the following annotation to be used as part of a Spring MVC validation. Unfortunately, I'm getting the following exception:

> Constraint annotation types must have at least one of the element
>   types FIELD, METHOD, TYPE or ANNOTATION_TYPE as target.

Are annotations prohibited from using `ElementType.PARAMETER` in the `@Target` annotation?

```
package com.jason.app.service.control.validator;


import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
//@Target({PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {ZipCodeValidator.class})
public @interface ZipCode {

    String message() default "Must be a valid 5-digit zip code";
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

}
```

Usage example of the annotation:

```
public ResponseBody<List<Order>> getOrdersByZipCode(@Valid @ZipCode String zipCode) {
   // method body
}
```

Java version is Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining annotation on class so use [ElementType.TYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#TYPE)

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
```

> Class, interface (including annotation type), or enum declaration

Comment: I added a usage example of how I'm using the Parameter. It's validating a String (ultimately against a regular expression).

Comment: @Jason see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50882444/can-spring-annotation-access-method-parameters