# Spring method annotations null

Tags: java, spring

I'am trying to get the methods that are using a custom annotation, but when i get the method, i can't get any annotation from it, every paramter that cites "annotation" is null.

My annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String value() default "";
}
```

Class using annotation:

```
public interface Interface {
    void doSomething();
}

@Repository
public class ImplementationClass implements Interface {
    
    @Override
    @MyAnnotation("some_value")
    public void doSomething() {

    }
}
```

Getting annotation:

```
@Configuration
public class MyAnnotationScanner implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {

        for (String beanName : applicationContext.getBeanNamesForAnnotation(Repository.class)) {
            Object bean = applicationContext.getBean(beanName);
            for (Method beanMethod : bean.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
                if (beanMethod.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class))
                    // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to get the correct method, but when i check with intellij it has no annotations and the "isAnnotationPresent" method always returns false.

Comment: Are these beans proxies?

Comment: How do i know that? Never heard about it.

Comment: `@Repository` annotated class is automatically proxiedby `Spring`

Comment: See some of the techniques in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121551/is-it-possible-to-unproxy-a-spring-bean

Comment: With this AopUtils class, i tried using all the "isProxy" methods, none of them returned true. "obj instanceof Advised" returned false too

Comment: The bean is a proxy, as Sotirios said. Maybe you can use BeanPostProcessor, which can do something with the bean before it's proxied. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-extension

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in using the `AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation()` method.

Basically for every `beanMethod`, you get the annotation using the `findAnnotation` method.

```java
var annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(beanMethod, MyAnnotation.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using `isAnnotationPresent` method but it was always returning false. I have then used `AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, <Annotation.class>)`

Here is how I am finding method that is using custom annotation:

```
for (String beanName : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
        Object bean = applicationContext.getBean(beanName);
        Class<?> objClass = bean.getClass();
        for (Method m : objClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {

            Annotation a = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(m, <Annotation_NAME>.class);
            if (a != null) {
```