# JsonMappingException when using @RefreshScope on a property bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

## JsonMappingException when using @RefreshScope on a property bean

I have a spring boot application which use spring cloud for the configuration

My configuration class looks like this:

```
package test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties("configuration")
@RefreshScope
public class MyConfigurationBean {

  @Value("${configuration.projectName}")
  private String name;
  private String city;
  private int port;

  // Getters/setters
}
```

And a RESTController that looks like this:

```
package test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RefreshScope
public class MyRestController {

  @Autowired
  private MyConfigurationBean config;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/config", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public MyConfigurationBean port() {
    return this.config;
  }
}
```

The /refresh endpoint is also enabled.

When I try a GET on /config, I have this exception:

```
2017-09-19 11:46:25.694  WARN 23005 --- [nio-5858-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: test.MyConfigurationBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3a7ee0c3["targetSource"]->org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource["beanFactory"]->org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory["parentBeanFactory"]->org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory["beanExpressionResolver"])
```

When I remove the `@RefreshScope` annotation from the `MyConfigurationBean` class, the error disapear, but the bean is not refresh when I call the `/refresh` endpoint.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Because you've put a bunch of annotations on `MyConfigurationBean` it is a proxy, which gives you the error. Why do want to return a config bean? Might be a situation for a DTO.

Comment: In fact, I just want to have a (Java)Bean with properties from the spring cloud config server that can be refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same exception and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37946701) to question [Casting a Spring's Proxy object to the actual runtime class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5976247)

Basically `RefreshScope` creates a CGLib proxy on your original property object which is not json serializable.

Casting e.g. `(MyConfigurationBean)((Advised) config).getTargetSource().getTarget()` should work, but it's strongly not *advised*.